# Threading doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application, which is to repeat the numbers what I hear then record the digits what I read. The numbers are `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. I use a for loop to play these numbers with a text to speech skill, which is from a third party.

For the recording part, I have to put it in a separate thread by the third party requirement. To record the voice, the method is likely:

```
 recordVoiceResource.Record(fileName);
```

To stop it, use:

```
 recordVoiceResource.Stop();
```

Now I find sometimes my recording is 0 second, which means the code perhaps doesn't reach `Record` line. Sometimes it only has 2 seconds. I believe the thread schedule is wrong.

```
 private ManualResetEvent terminate = new ManualResetEvent(false);

 PlayTTS("Please repeat the following numbers as you hear them.");

                Thread t = new Thread(() => RecordNumbers());
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                terminate.Set();
                terminate.WaitOne();
                PlayNumbers();
                recordVoiceResource.Stop();
```

The thread method is:

```
    private void RecordNumbers()
    {
        recordVoiceResource = TelephonyServer.GetVoiceResource();
        recordVoiceResource.MaximumSilence = 1;
        recordVoiceResource.MaximumTime = 30;
        // Start recording what I read from I heard
        recordVoiceResource.Record(fileName);
    }
```

To playNumbers,

```
    private void PlayNumbers()
    {
        foreach (var item in numbers)
        {
            try
            {
                vr.PlayTTS(item.ToString()); // will be 0,1,2,...9
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
```

Comment: Why Thread.Sleep???...Avoid it like the DEVIL

Comment: I have to wait 2 seconds between each number, thus I can hear it clearly.Play back “0 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 9” allowing 2 seconds between each number for the caller to repeat it.

Comment: What's your ManualResetEvent waiting for?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My question is it doesn't record the voice as I stated already.

Comment: -@Marc, I am not sure whether I should use ManualResetEvent. Basically I want to the steps are: record, playNumbers then stop. But the record should be in a thread.

Comment: Have you tested recording without playing simultaneously?  Does `Record()` return immediately?  What does the `MaximumSilence` property do?

Comment: +1 for `MaximumSilence` -- I suspect this may be causing the recording to terminate after 1 second of nothing spoken, and if there is a two second gap between numbers, well... do the math.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, that's what I was suspecting.  Love, is there a reason you haven't divulged the source of your voice and recording SDKs? That might help with getting expert eyes on your question.

Comment: The third party is from http://help.voiceelements.com/. As for MaximumSilence: Gets or sets the maximum silence in seconds that will be allowed until termination of the next voice function. Default = 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, the property `MaximumSilence` gets or sets the maximum silence in seconds that will be allowed until termination of the next voice function.  You are setting it to one second, starting the recording, and then sleeping for two seconds before beginning playback that prompts the user to say something.  Do you see the problem here?  Assuming the mic doesn't pick up some unrelated speech during that period, the recording will stop before the playback even begins.

Since there is a 2-second gap between number playback, you probably need to set `MaximumSilence` to several seconds.

That is, of course, assuming your intention was to capture a single recording of the user speaking all the numbers (which is how your code is written).  If you want to capture the spoken numbers individually, then you may need to schedule and synchronize separate recordings as each number is played back.  You may want to double-check the API to make sure your solution is what you intended.

Comment: -@Mike, I removed the first Thread.Sleep(2000), which is before beginning playback. Also I set MaximumSilence=0, it works out. According to your answer, yes. If MaximumSilence = 4, which is great than 2 then it works. Thanks. Do I need still use ManualResetEvent?

Comment: @Love You may want to use the `ManualResetEvent` to wait for the recording thread to complete (in which case you need to set it at the end of `RecordNumbers`).  But `t.Join()` should also work (waits for thread to complete).

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely your problem is causing due to `Thread.Sleep()`. Use a timer instead:

```
System.Timers.Timer Record = new System.Timers.Timer();
Record.Interval = 2000;
Record.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Record_Elapsed);

            void Record_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {                   
                 Record.Enabled=false;                  
                 PlayNumbers();
                 recordVoiceResource.Stop();
            }
```

And set:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => RecordNumbers());
              t.Start();
              Record.Enabled=true;
```

Comment: -@apomene, you code is not working. Please double check the usage of terminate, I doubt it.

Comment: -@apomene, I appreciate your answer but your code is still not working. After running the code, it went to the final block then jumped to the thread. I just found the solution of my question, set MaximumSilence = 0 based on my original code then it works out. But not sure why? Need more research on it.